# SearchController issue in UITableview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

In my code i added `UISearchController` as `UITableView` Header.
But if User scroll `UItableview` then searcher is goes up & hide.
I want to show `UISearchBar` stick to top.

I don't want to add it in navigation title.

I also try to add in `UIViewController` but it is disappear when try to search something.

Please help me to solve this.

Thank you,

Comment: Create custom SearchBar using TextFiled resolve your problem.

Comment: go through this sample https://github.com/versluis/Table-Search-2015 you will get some idea

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the UISearchBar in the header of the UITableView. Put it outside the UITableView. It just means that your view controller will have to subclass UIViewController instead of UITableViewController.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried this but **I also try to add in UIViewController but it is disappear when try to search something.**